# How to rectify Error #1064 in MariaDB procedure?

Tags: sql, database, mariadb, procedure, mysql-error-1064

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_priority_rows()
BEGIN
  DECLARE max_heuristics INT DEFAULT 10;
  DECLARE heuristic_ID INT;

  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT heuristicID
    FROM heuristics;
    
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
  FOR NOT FOUND SET heuristic_ID = 0;
    
  DECLARE @study_ID INT;

  SELECT MAX(studyID) INTO @study_ID FROM study;

  OPEN cur;

  REPEAT
    FETCH cur INTO heuristic_ID;
    IF heuristic_ID = 0 THEN
      LEAVE;
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO heuristic_priority (studyID, heuristicID, h_priority)
    VALUES (@study_ID, heuristic_ID, 'm');
  UNTIL heuristicID = 0 END REPEAT;

  CLOSE cur;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

It throws up an error as follows:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near '@study_ID INT;

What should I do to rectify this issue?

Comment: You can't declare the type of `@` variables in MySQL. Use a normal variable like you do with `max_heuristics` and `heuristic_ID`.

Comment: Why do you need this loop? Just use `INSERT INTO heursitic_priority (columns...) SELECT ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need most of that code. The loop can be replaced with this query:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE insert_priority_rows()
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO heuristic_priority (studyID, heuristicID, h_priority)
    SELECT m.max_study_id, h.heuristicID, 'm'
    FROM heuristics AS h
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(studyID) as max_study_id FROM study) AS m;
END$$
```

Comment: Can you tell me exactly where I need to replace this code? It would be great if you could show directly as a code.

Comment: Now it throws up this error:

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

Comment: Did you remove the `DELIMITER` statement? I didn't intend that, I was just showing the change to the procedure body.

Comment: This time it didn't show up any error but when I create a new study the heuristic_priority table is not automatically generating the foreign keys from study table and heuristic table. It stays blank.

Comment: This procedure won't be run automatically when you create a new study. You could use a trigger to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! I used CALL syntax to run the procedure automatically when a new entry is made in study table.